# How does the Venom Gauntlet poison damage work?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

In Mass Effect 3, the Cabal Canguard character has a class power Venom Gauntlet. A passive bonus is the following:

> 30% of melee damage is applied as poison damage over 5 seconds.

If I attack an enemy, does it get 70% of the attack right away, and the spare 30% in those 5 seconds, or does it instantly hits for 100%, and is the 30% extra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deal 70% of the damage with the melee and then the remaining 30% is dealt over 5 Seconds. The power also gives you a health & Shield Bonus of 25%  and a Melee Bonus of 15% making the trade off worthwhile.

Sidenote when you get this up to rank 6 the melee damage boost is brilliant and makes the whole tree amazing if you are a fan of melee.

*(for the most fun with melee Krogan Warlord Sentinel)*

Comment: But why? That sucks. And I just LOVE the Krogan Warlord

Comment: its to balance it because otherwise the boosts are just too powerful compared to the other classes in that group